# Javascript array returns ["item1", "item2", dedup: function, contains: function]

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I wrote a function to check all the checkbox inputs on the page and put the "checked" ones into an array. The checked values make it in correctly, but I'm also getting these "dedup: function, contains: function" values. Why?

Here's my function:

```
var custTreatments = [];

function Checkform() {
  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    custTreatments.push($(this).val());
    return custTreatments;
  });
}   

Checkform();
```

HTML is really simple:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="item1" />item1
<input type="checkbox" value="item2" />item2
<input type="checkbox" value="item3" />item3
```

Thanks!

Comment: you may have to change the implementation to `function Checkform() {
    return $(':checkbox:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
}

var custTreatments = Checkform();`

Comment: What libraries are you using? It looks like something is extending `Object` or extending jQuery collections.

Comment: It looks like arrays are extended with some additional methods somehow?

Comment: looks like some library is adding those methods to Array, it should be harmless

Comment: What do you mean that you're "getting" those values? Where are you getting them? Are you using `for-in` on your `custTreatments` array?

Comment: When I log out custTreatments to the console I get [“item1”, “item2”, dedup: function, contains: function]

Comment: And how about when you log `custTreatments[3]` or `custTreatments[custTreatments.length-1]`?

Comment: dedup sounds like deduplication. have you got some sort of library added in your project that could be interfering with it? Have you maybe tried to clear the array each time you run `CheckForm()`?

`function Checkform() {
  custTreatments = [];
  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    custTreatments.push($(this).val());
  });
  return custTreatments;
}` http://jsfiddle.net/Hx39j/

Comment: Unless you provide us with the necessary information to reproduce the problem, there is little we can do. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Is there actually an issue in your code, or are you just worried about the `console.log()` representation?

Answer (score -1):

Edit the js implementation to:

```
var custTreatments = [];

function Checkform() {
  $('[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
    custTreatments.push($(this).val());
    return custTreatments;
  });
}   

Checkform();
```

**UPDATE**

I check it. I made a mistake. T_T

> $( ":checkbox" ) is equivalent to $( "[type=checkbox]" )

Your code seems to work fine.

Test on http://jsfiddle.net/B274h/1/

Can you reproduce it again?

Comment: So you suggest to use `[type=checkbox]` instead of `:checkbox`? Why? Why would it solve the OP's problem? Please **explain** your solution.